# external library update in a SVN repository

Tags: svn

In my repository, I store several external libraries. When a new version of a library is available, I do the following tasks to update it in my repository:

1. checkout my old version of the library
2. recursively remove everything but *.svn* directories
3. copy the new version of the library
4. svn status to see the changes
5. add new files and directories, delete removed files and directories
6. commit

Is there a better (or simpler) way to achieve this task ?

Note that I **cannot** use svn:externals because only a few of the libraries I use provide a SVN access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is actually the cleanest way to manage a vendor branch, especially if you have your own customizations to the code.

In many cases it may not be really needed to track deleted files of the external lib, but OTOH it's easily scripted, so I would keep using this procedure. I do it the same way, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a pretty fast way to do this, if you are on a Mac and have XCode installed. I'm sure there must be other file compare apps that can do this, but this is the one I have and tested it with.

Open FileMerge (/Developer/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge) and under Compare files, choose the old version as the left and the new version as the right. Hit compare, and then on the resulting screen, select all the directories and files in the left column. Then, under the "Merge" dropdown, select "Use right" or hit Cmd-3. You may be asked to specify a merge directory. If you are, browse to the original version's directory and select that.

If you `svn status` in the library's directory now, you will see a list of the changed files. `svn add` or `svn delete` the ones marked with `?` or `!`. Check in!

If you screw up at any point during the process and want to start over, it's easy:

```
find . -type f -not -path '*.svn*' -exec rm {} \;
svn update --depth=infinity .
```

Answer (score 1):

I think svn externals are what you are looking for.  Some good documentation can be found here:  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Comment: thanks but usually, external libraries I use don't necessarily from another SVN repository.

Comment: Externals doesn't need to come from another svn repository.
Here's what you do, say you have /svn/myproject/trunk/lib/libfoo/
which contain the 3. party library. What you do is instead make
/svn/3dparty/libs/libfoo-1.4.53/ and use svn externals to link into 
/svn/myproject/trunk/lib/libfoo/ . when a new version comes out you just place that in /svn/3dparty/libs/libfoo-1.4.54/ and link that version in instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new repository for each library. Then, when a new version arrives, just copy it into the trunk of the library repository and you should see the modifications and new files identified by SVN - there's no need to remove the old files first. Deleted files are another matter - but I would hope your libraries aren't losing files like crazy so you can probably manage this by hand.

Then, once all your changes are checked in you can tag the trunk as the updated version (probably to match the version of the library) and include that tag as an external to the consuming project.

Comment: Will have problems if some files were deleted in new version. You will then end up with a mutant.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete whole directory in svn and add it again with new version (assuming a library is in its own directory and not mixed in with other libs). You don't need manufactured history for third party library anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, I copy a source tree into a repo I have set up for tracking it locally.

When a new version is available:

- I fetch the library files directly ontop of my WC.
- I view an changes (using tortoise -
  its easy to see which have changed,
  the overlays change)
- I commit all the changes.

Its that simple. Obviously you don't get full change history as you're only tracking the 1 version at a time, committing the latest changes, but otherwise its very effective.